# Android Studio throws "image not found" exception

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem. When I was set an image in my image button then it correctly shown in design view but when I run the program then my app unfortunately stop and shows the error "resource not found" exception.

How can I fix this problem?

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login_button"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/enter"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/enter" />
```

My image name is `enter.png`.

Comment: Please share the error details.

Comment: without seeing error code details its hard to find the issue. so please share the error details.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring this button in your code, but it doesn't have an id to refer to. You need to android:id to your xml here then refer to it in your code.